# How to find the file that is causing the exception in the compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, roslyn

so, i have a weird problem. So i have this enterprise code of my company... around 6000files and 200k lines of code.
Something is causing the compiler to crash:
Error   MSB6006 "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797.

I have already seen that some people reported the same error.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22-2146232797%22

It is difficult for me to locate the file that is causing trouble.
I was wondering:

1. Which file is causing this?
2. Is there any way to attach the debugger to this csc.exe and get a memory?
3. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Go into Build options and enable the Output window on Build start

Comment: The other answers are talking about the Output window. Even when vs2017 is set to maximum diagnostic output, **csc.exe** will not show the progress as it executes files, and generally all files must be included in a single invocation of **csc.exe**. One hacky workaround to view the progress and estimate which file is causing the compiler to crash would be to start the Windows ResourceMonitor disk activity view (or better yet, SysInternals 'ProcessExplorer'). Since MSB6006 "csc.exe" -2146232797 is a FailFast, the last file might be near the culprit. Make sure to empty disk cache by rebooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general tips for troubleshooting mystery error codes:

1. Use windows calculator to convert the error number from decimal to hex.  In this case it's 0x80131623.
2. Google that number. In this case it sounds like it could be a FatalExecutionEngineError, which could be an indication of an internal stack overflow.
3. Look in the Windows Event Log. There's a good chance you'll find the full stack trace hiding in there, which may point you to the error.
4. Turn up the level of the error reporting. In visual studio: Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build and Run / MSBuild verbosity

200k lines is a big project, but not enormous. CSC should be able to handle that kind of size. But it may have to do with how it's internally structured.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I doubt OP has the Output window open so #4 might not be much use.  Remember Output window is not shown by default during builds of c#